# Systemd: how to start service after another service started

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-18.04, systemd-service

I have these two services, one is Google start up script service and second one is redis service, I want to start redis service once the startup script service is started and done, I have these following systemd config but my redis services won't start with these config

```
google-startup-scripts.service
[Unit]
Description=Google Compute Engine Startup Scripts
After=network-online.target network.target rsyslog.service
After=google-instance-setup.service google-network-daemon.service
After=cloud-final.service multi-user.target
Wants=cloud-final.service
After=snapd.seeded.service
Wants=snapd.seeded.service

[Service]
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup
KillMode=process
Type=oneshot
StandardOutput=journal+console
Environment=PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

```
redis.service

[Unit]
Description=Redis In-Memory Data Store
After=google-startup-scripts.service

[Service]
Type=notify
PIDFile=/run/redis-6378.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-getdevice /etc/redis-getdevice/6378.conf
ExecStop=/usr/bin/redis-cli -p 6378 shutdown
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

once the google-startup-script.service run and it do the operations and goes to state exited. and redis service doesn't start at all (I'm using `After` in unit) what I'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 16):

There a number of different keywords to specify systemd unit dependencies. Each  with a slightly different effect and implications with regards to failure handling and for example "starting" and "waiting for startup to complete" for example :

**[`Wants`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Wants=)**

> Configures (weak) requirement dependencies on other units. ... Units listed in this option will be started if the configuring unit is. ...

**[`Requires`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Requires=)**

> Similar to Wants=, but declares a stronger requirement dependency. ... If this unit gets activated, the units listed will be activated as well. If one of the other units fails to activate, and an ordering dependency After= on the failing unit is set, this unit will not be started. ...

**[`After`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=)**

> ... If unit `foo.service` contains the setting `Before=bar.service` and both units are being started, `bar.service`'s start-up is delayed until foo.service has finished starting up. `After=` is the inverse of `Before=`, i.e. while `Before=` ensures that the configured unit is started before the listed unit begins starting up, `After=` ensures the opposite, that the listed unit is fully started up before the configured unit is started. ...

In that regard your redid.service Unit, with a `After=google-startup-scripts.service` dependancy,  appears correct.

Your issue would seem to be that the google-startup-scripts.service is [`Type=oneshot`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=). The  systemd  service manager will consider the unit up after the main `ExecStart=`  process exits.

What can happen is that a script  triggers tasks to start and run *in the background* and doesn't wait for those to complete (or to complete their start-up). The script will continue to the next steps and then successfully complete, systemd considers the unit to be up, but one or more processes are not quite there yet.

You may need to make an adjustment in whatever is running from `/usr/bin/google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup`

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html

> Along with a unit file foo.service, the directory foo.service.wants/ may exist. All unit files symlinked from such a directory are implicitly added as dependencies of type Wants= to the unit. Similar functionality exists for Requires= type dependencies as well, the directory suffix is .requires/ in this case. This functionality is useful to hook units into the start-up of other units, without having to modify their unit files.

In your case your specific, you can remove `[Install]` section from unit file.

You could also use `PartOf=systemgoogle-startup-scripts.service` under the `[Unit]` section.

`systemctl disable redis.service`

`systemctl stop redis.service`

`mkdir /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemgoogle-startup-scripts.service`

`cd /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemgoogle-startup-scripts.service`

`ln -s ../redis.service .` (adjust to you needs).

`systemctl enable redis.service`

`systemctl restart systemgoogle-startup-scripts.service`

`systemctl status redis.service`

If all went as planned, from the output you will notice that it is now loaded as a static service and active.